# A column subtracting button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code that uses a select statement to SQL to generate data based on a specific date range. It works fine and does what I want. Two of those columns are what my question is about and that is F and H. F is the Payment Amount and H is the balance. G in this case is suppose to be the amount spent(which is the difference between payment amount and balance). What I'm trying to do is after the query runs and I'm given x amount of entries that if I press a button F in every row is subtracted by the corresponding H is that same row and the result goes into column G

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Range("G11").End(xlDown).Formula = Range("F11").End(xlDown).Value - Range("H11").End(xlDown).Value
End Sub
```

The SQL starts inserting the data at the 12th row hence why I have G11.End(xlDown).

Basically what I'm hoping for is something like  if data is in the 12th row in F/H and is 8,3 and in the 20th row as like 13,5 than G in both the 12th and 20th row would be 5 and 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can paste a single formula over a range, provided you write it with dynamic, non-fixed($) notation, so that it will use the equivalent row/column throughout such that:

```
dim lr as long
lr = cells(rows.count,"F").end(xlup).row 'finds the last row in column F
range(cells(12,"G"),cells(lr,"G")).formula = "=F12-H12" 'note that the formula destination and the source data start on 12
```

If you foresee a change from row 11, or just want to make it easier to fix later, you can do something like:

```
dim lr as long, r as long
r = 12 'can change this, or make in inputbox... 
lr = cells(rows.count,"F").end(xlup).row 'finds the last row in column F
range(cells(r,"G"),cells(lr,"G")).formula = "=F" & r & "-H" & r
```

---

**Edit1:** changed all the 11s to 12s

---

**Edit2:**  Will deal with the sheets problem (using the second code only, since it'll be easier to modify in the future):

```
With Sheets("Report")
    dim lr as long, r as long
    r = 12 'can change this, or make in inputbox... 
    lr = .cells(.rows.count,"F").end(xlup).row 'finds the last row in column F
    .range(.cells(r,"G"),.cells(lr,"G")).formula = "=F" & r & "-H" & r
End With
```

I copy/pasted each of the codes I provided initially and verified that they work when associated with a module.

Comment: Thanks. Im trying this now. I got Object doesn't support this property or method error message when trying to first one. I didn't mention it but the button and columns are on different sheets. Button is on Sheets(Start) columns are on Sheets(Report). I doubt that's why I'm getting this particular error message but ill try the second version.

Comment: Hmm so it get's the right calculation and puts it in the correct column but it's not going to the right sheet. If its too much work I might just end up putting the button on the Report sheet. This much help has been great.

Comment: @JoeBlack did you ensure the sheet name is updated for yours?  `With Sheets("Report")` in my code.  In testing, this does put the exact formula into the Report sheet, no matter where I launch the code from (button on random sheet or alt+f8 menu were both checked).

Comment: lol Thanks for the help it works as I hoped. I had .range(.cells(r,"G).cells(lr,"G")). I didn't put the comma before the .cells. Removing that made all the difference. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @JoeBlack not a problem.  please mark this as answered (checkbox to the left of my post) so this doesn't stay listed as unanswered.